# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy for C# API

Tags: c#, reactjs, cors

I created an API using C# for a backend controller for my React Web Page. In that API I have multiple endpoints using GET, POST, DELETE and PUT methods.

I have no issues when using the GET and POST methods from it directly from my web page but I'm getting an error when doing a DELETE or PUT method to it.

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http‍://myBackEndDomain.example.com/resourcePath' from origin 'http‍://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

This is the CORS configuration of my API in C#:

```
//Cors
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("_corsPolicy",
                          policy =>
                          {
                              policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowCredentials();
                          });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("_corsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

One thing to note is that it works with Postman and it works if I use an extension to deactivate the CORS policy from my browser (so I assume it has something to do with the server CORS configuration that I shared).

Edit: added Postman successful response headers.
[image]

Comment: can you add postman response headers to your question?

Comment: If the error occurs in a static file move `UseCors` before `UseStaticFiles`, otherwise double-check the origin.

Comment: @ali updated the post with them.

Comment: @Max I modified it but got the same error